# How to verify inputs to a private method?

Tags: java, exception, assertions

I have a private method (eg: binary search) that expects certain input (eg: an array which is sorted).
How should it guard against invalid inputs such as unsorted array as an input ?

A public method can throw an exception, but what should be a behavior of private method?

Comment: A private method can also throw an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define a custom exception for your method and can throw that exception from your method

Answer (score 1):

you can validate the inputs to a private method also and throw the exception from a private method also